# Stop new line htm js

Tags: javascript, html

how to stop new line when i press enter, in database i get and < br>...

---

---

---

---

```
    function post_Comment(text, post_id, event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey == 0) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../ajax/post_comment.php",
            data: { get_text : text, post_id : post_id },
            cache: false,
            success: function(){
                $(".writecomment_" + post_id).val('');
            }
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
<textarea onkeyup="post_Comment(this.value, <?php echo $post['id']; ?>, event);" placeholder='Write a comment...'></textarea>
```

Comment: You will either have to remove them yourself serverside or clientside.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually understand what you want, but if you want to remove line breaks you can do the following.

```
data: { get_text : text, post_id : post_id }
```

Replace this with:

```
data: { get_text : text.replace('\n', ' '), post_id : post_id }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your textarea newline values has been converted into `<br>` tag. you need to trim them on your PHP file. Since, the POST method has been triggered when user pressing enter key, look at your JS

```
if(event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey == 0) {
  $.ajax({
```